# Process captured image from camera to get image which looks like scanned document

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera, image-scanner

I am new to android camera and image processing so my question can be little naive.

I want to capture a document and upload it just the way google drive supports. capture an image and process it to look like as if it was scanned.

is there any android library which will be helpful in my case ?

PS I don’t want OCR, just want to scan image taken using camera.

This is when images is captured.

[image: This is when images is captured.]

This is how the processed image should look like as if it was scanned

[image: processed image]

Comment: Do you have an example of a single image in both forms (as taken by a camera, and post-processed to look as if it was scanned), perhaps from a different platform?  I'm not picturing what result it is you want.

Comment: I am too looking for the answer. Thinking of using OpenCV or JavaCV not sure how much those will be helpful. Any answer on this would be helpful